# AngularJS is not responding to touch events after adding deviceready listener

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

This is my code:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {

  Some JavaScript here.

  angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector('html'), ['ionicApp']);

}, false);

angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
        .controller("ionicControl", ['$scope', '$interval', function ($scope, $interval) {

  Some Angular JS code

}]);
```

This is my markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
.
.
.
<body ng-controller="ionicControl">
<ion-pane>
    <ion-content>
        <canvas id="canvas" on-touch="moveBall($event)" on-release="stopBall()"></canvas>
```

When I remove the `deviceready` listener, everything works but when I add it the screen becomes blank. There are no errors in the console though.

UPDATE: After reading some related question on SO. I found out that after adding `var ionicApp =` before the Angular module the screen starts drawing stuff but there is still no response to touch events.

```
var ionicApp = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])
        .controller("ionicControl", ['$scope', '$interval', function ($scope, $interval) {

  Some Angular JS code

}]);
```

will

Comment: Probably because `deviceready` is not firing. Try `DOMContentLoaded`.

Comment: @Tushar why won't it fire though?